# Removing element from innermost nested Iterator in java causes NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iterator, nested, nosuchelementexception

I keep crashing and getting  java.util.NoSuchElementException at the if statement. I was under the impression that while(Iterator.hasNext()) ensured that a Iterator.next() call wouldn't cause a buffer overrun.

What is the correct algorithm to loop through two nested iterators, and remove elements from one of the iterators when a match is found, without throwing such an exception (which I *think* is caused by overrunning the array bounds)?

enter code here
 {

```
    Iterator<Integer> d = entitiesDeleteQueue.iterator();
    Iterator<Entity> e = entities.iterator();


    while (d.hasNext()) {

        while (e.hasNext()) {

            if (d.next() == e.next().getEntityId())

                e.remove();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider exactly what happens if `entities` have three elements, and `entitiesDeleteQueue` have two.  You may want to run it on paper.

Comment: d.next() will overrun on the last e.hasNext() iteration. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I see that I'm advancing the outermost iterator inside the loop every time next() is called. The effect that I want is that of a nested for loop, where each iteration of the outer loop compares one outer element to every inner element. To achieve this I would have to invoke the outer loop's iterator element without advancing it, while I'm in the inner loop. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your two `hasNext` conditions to avoid overrun of either iterator:

```
while (d.hasNext() && e.hasNext()) {
    if (d.next() == e.next.getEntityId())
        e.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nesting iterators isn't as straightforward as nesting for loops. It requires assigning Iterator.next() to an object reference, that way the iterator doesn't advance every time you need to access the element. The referencing must be done in each layer of the nest, and the second iterator must be created inside the outer loop. Then you can perform operations without overrunning the ArrayList by too many next() calls.

```
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
List<Entity> entityDeleteQueue = new ArrayList<Entity>(); 

Iterator<Entity> e = entities.iterator();

    while (e.hasNext()) {

        Entity liveEntity = e.next();
        Iterator<Entity> d = entityDeleteQueue.iterator();

        while (d.hasNext()) {

            Entity deadEntity = d.next();

            if( deadEntity.getEntityId() == liveEntity.getEntityId()){

                System.out.println("Dead entity: " + deadEntity.getEntityId());

                System.out.println("Removing entity " + liveEntity.getEntityId());

                e.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    for (Entity survivor: entities){

        System.out.println("Remaining entity: " + survivor.getEntityId());
    }
```